# find average of json field in postgres rails

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, postgresql-9.4

```
id  name    overview                created_at
1   john    { 'keywords' => '10' }  2017-02-11 04:55:23 UTC
2   robert  { 'keywords' => '20' }  2017-02-12 04:55:23 UTC
3   litty   { 'keywords' => '10' }  2017-02-13 04:55:23 UTC
4   john    { 'keywords' => '20' }  2017-02-14 04:55:23 UTC
5   john    { 'keywords' => '30' }  2017-02-15 04:55:23 UTC
6   litty   { 'keywords' => '20' }  2017-02-16 04:55:23 UTC
7   robert  { 'keywords' => '40' }  2017-02-17 04:55:23 UTC
8   litty   { 'keywords' => '50' }  2017-02-18 04:55:23 UTC
```

find records by **unique** `name` and having `max(created_at)`.
the output should be like following

```
id  name    overview                created_at
5   john    { 'keywords' => '30' }  2017-02-15 04:55:23 UTC
7   robert  { 'keywords' => '40' }  2017-02-17 04:55:23 UTC
8   litty   { 'keywords' => '50' }  2017-02-18 04:55:23 UTC
```

Then need to find average of the JSON field value `overview->keywords`

The final result based on the given example should be `40`